# Data Dictionary and Oracle Advice needed

Tags: database, oracle, attributes, many-to-many, data-dictionary

I have four tables called (to make the post easier to understand) a,b,c and d.

I have created a data dictionary for them all, with all attributes and other information needed. I am confused on whether or not I have to include my many-to-many tables (e.g. a_b) in the data dictionary too?

Also, do I need to have the many-to-many tables in the Oracle database too?

Comment: @Mina - of course we can build a data dictionary for our application.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build a data dictionary, presumably explaining the usage of your tables and columns in your applications.  This is a good idea.

It is better to include all tables, including intersection (many-to-many) tables.  Firstly, because it is useful to understand why we have M:N relationships rather than the more-normal 1:M relationships.  Secondly, because including all tables instils a discipline which means the data dictionary is more likely to be maintained (it is just another forma of documentation, and people tend not to keep documentation up-to-date).

As for whether you need intersection tables, well, yes.   yYou need a physical data model which is accurate.   If you have relationships between tables which cannot be reduced to one-to-many then you have to implement them as many-to-many.

The alternative is to enforce the relationship entirely in application code and that *always leads to data corruption*.  Ignore anybody who says otherwise.  The arguments of history are against them.